Funds missing after solana purchase
I have recently opened a phantom wallet first transaction of 16$ AUD of Solana was perfect then I decided to buy more the best 50, 16 and another 16 $ transactions did not appear in my wallet even though I’ve definitely spent the money on them I also noticed in my first account that I had two insanely small 0.000000001 transactions into my account both containing a similar signatory .gg with a emoji or something I thought someone “dusted” the f outa me then I open a new account then boom doesn’t work again I then see there’s trouble with phantoms payments. Will I get my money back if the transactions don’t go through epically on my first account that I deleted ? And does the 0.00000001 transactions into my account mean I’ve gotten dusted ?
